# Create foreign key with delete on cascade with PetaPoco in Umbraco and C#

Tags: c#, umbraco, poco

Using [PetaPoco](http://www.toptensoftware.com/petapoco/), I want to create dynamically two tables in Umbraco database.

I followed the examples from [here](https://nddt-webdevelopment.de/umbraco/create-custom-database-table-umbraco-petapoco) and I want to add a rule to foreign key that enable delete cascade.

I didn't find any example about this.

The `ForeignKey` attribute does not this stuff.

```
[ForeignKey(typeof(ParentModel), Name = "TheNameOfForeignKey", Column = "TheColumnId")]
```

How to setup foreign key with delete oncascade using PetaPoco ?

Comment: I don't understand the question - do you mean you want to create two tables programmatically in the database?